# PHP/Mysql Radius search between x y coordinates

Tags: php, mysql, coordinates, radius

I have got the (dutch) x y coordinates of a person and the x y coordinates from different locations in the database, for example:

```
x = 158322
y = 460782
```

Now i would like to find all the locations in a radius of 15km around the location of the person.
What is the best way to find this and can you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how much data you have, you'll need to calculate the distance between your fixed point and each point in your dataset. If the dataset is large, you can get all points in a 15km boundingbox first and then calculate the distances for the points that match.

To calculate the distance in php, you can do something like this:

```
$distance = sqrt(($x-$x2)^2+($y-$y2)^2 // = pythagoras a^2+b^2=c^2
```

Ofcourse this assumes the earth is flat. If you need to compensate for the curvature of the earth, do a google search for "calculate distance between two coordinates".

If I remember correctly, the "dutch coordinates" you mention are in meters, so getting a 15km bounding box should be as simple as `x +/- 15000` and `y +/- 15000`

Btw, mysql has a sqrt function, so technically you can do all of this in mysql.

Also, if you need code to convert Rijksdriehoekscoördinaten to GPS coordinates, let me know ;)